# How to display in QGIS a mountain saddle with a symbol which indicates the orientation of the saddle?

Tags: qgis-3, markers, point-of-interest, overpass-turbo

I exported mountain saddles (natural=saddle) from overpass-turbo.eu as GeoJSON.
I manged to display the saddles on a map with a symbol/marker like a point.

I'd rather like to display the saddles on the map with an icon which indicates a saddle and also **indicates the orientation of the saddle** like it is common on maps.

Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: For the icon, you have to import an image or SVG into QGIS to symbolize your point geometry. For the orientation, have you a field with this information in the attribute table ? (or a way to have this information ?)

Answer (score 4):

You need the information on the orientation of the saddle clockwise in degree from North/0° as an attribute. Then use [`data defined override`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#data-defined) on the rotation of the symbol, handing it the field containing the orientation value.

Comment: thanks. it seems to me that the difficult part will be getting the orientation. It's not in the osm tags. I believe I've to calculate it myself from dem/srtm data :-(